# Check me on this modulation question?

Tags: communication, modulation, fourier, laplace-transform

I need to check my answers for parts (a) and (c);

a) I got  q(t) = p(t)cos(5pit)

c) i got  y(t) as a rectangle with amplitude 1 from -pi to pi. So, y(t) = 1/8 f(t)

Am I correct for both parts;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(a) looks good to me.

for (c), keep in mind that \$cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}2\$, so multiplying with a real valued sine wave will give you mirror images.